# TextChanged event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a GridView and a TextBox in one of its fields:

```
<asp:GridView ID="NTSBulkEditGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" Height="500px"
        DataKeyNames="BookStem" OnRowDataBound="NTSBulkEditGridView_RowDataBound" DataSourceID="NTSSqlDataSource">
<Columns>  
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="Priority">  
        <ItemTemplate>  
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPriority" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Priority") %>' BorderStyle="None" Width="80%" OnTextChanged="TextBox_Changed" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>  
            <asp:CompareValidator ID="PriorityCompareValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtPriority" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Priority must be an integer!" Text="*" Operator="DataTypeCheck" Type="Integer" ValidationGroup="InsertUpdateNewTitlesStatusValidation" ></asp:CompareValidator>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

...

Could you please tell me why TextBox_Changed() is never called when I change text and press Enter? I tried to put same kind of a TextBox outside of the GridView, and there it works.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe it is valid inside an ItemTemplate block. And it seems like your ID would be repeated and break stuff.

Comment: @Joe Tuskan No, it wouldn't be repeated. It will be automatically calced according to the controls tree

Comment: @Joe Tuskan The ID wouldnt matter gridviews take care of that. The real question is what does he want to do with the data, because that may force him to do something other than the TextChanged. He wont be able to tell what row he is editing with his current design.

Comment: @dreznik, as @saeed said; try hitting TAB rather ENTER.

Comment: You are typing only integers in the TextBox correct? Just wanted to make sure. :P

Comment: I tried hitting tab, without success. Yes, I am typing integers, otherwise validator complains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextChanged of an ASP.NET TextBox translates into `blur` JavaScript event. And `blur` occurs when the text of the input element is changed and the input element loses focus. Try to change the text, but don't hit Enter. Simply hit `TAB` key to go to next field. Does it fire post back?

Update:

Well, I saw that link. Two things. First, if you notice, it goes back to 2005 and ASP.NET 2.0 and we all know that 6 years in the world of computer means 60 years. So that article is obsolete by now. Second, sometimes a pattern only exists in articles, and you rarely see it in real productive systems. How many bulk actions have you seen on the web? And what type do they have? Consider Gmail, or Yahoo mail for example. You can mark 20 or 30 or X number of emails as read in one shot. But, can you respond to 20 mails in one step? Nope, just because it doesn't make sense. I've never seen a bulk action on a text box in web world. I think you'd better stick to use AJAX, with better performance, and more user acceptance. :)

Comment: Then let's see what's your business? Can you explain what do you want to do? Something like, "I want to let the users edit their email address", or "I'd like to provide inline-editing feature for salary field". Because there may be better and more effective ways :)

Comment: OK, I wanted to use a BulkEditGridView I found here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattdotson/archive/2005/11/09/real-world-gridview-bulk-editing.aspx. That GridView is derived from common GridView. I needed to be able to edit multiple fields at once. That GridView handles changes and stores changed GridViewRows in a list. I noticed that text change handler is never called. Then I decided to simplify the scenario and produced the code you saw. And it doesn't handle the text change, either.

Comment: What link? Are you asking about the code I mentioned? It is in my initial question. Its purpose was only to try to debug the problem. I am not going to use it as it is.

Comment: Saeed, it is not my choice. My users want the GridView to look and function similar to Excel. They want to be able to edit multiple cells. I realize the solution there may be obsolete, but I don't have anything better. If you could suggest something, I would appreceiate it. If not, I would like to at least fix the existing solution. And it is urgent, too :( What did you mean by using AJAX?

Comment: I added a button next to the textbox and handled its click. And that handler also is not called.